# How to improve this Class Module definition

Tags: excel, vba, oop

I'm trying to create a class module that takes two arguments, inputted by user, and then make a calculation to create a private property that returns a calculated value

Here is what I got so far:

```
'clsItem Class Module
Option Explicit

Private mQt As Integer
Private mPrice As Double
Private mTotal As Double

Public Property Let Quantity(Value As Integer)
    mQt = Value
End Property

Public Property Let Price(Value As Double)
    mPrice = Value
End Property

Private Function SetTotal(mQt As Integer, mVl As Double)
    mTotal = mQt * mPrice
End Function

Public Property Get Quantity() As Integer
    Quantity = mQt
End Property

Public Property Get Price() As Double
    Price = mPrice    
End Property

Public Property Get Total() As Double
    SetTotal mQt, mPrice 'This smells
    Total = mTotal   
End Property
```

The part where I've commented `This smells` is a kludge I put on so the code below gives the expected behavior:

```
'Object Module
Sub TestCls()
    Dim basicItem As clsItem

    Set basicItem = New clsItem
    With basicItem
        .Quantity = 100
        .Price = 12.5
    End With
    Debug.Print basicItem.Total
End Sub
```

I think this is wrong because

1. I'm using a get property to call a function, but I've couldn't figure a way to place this calling anywhere else on the code.
2. If I don't call `clsItem.Total` somewhere in the module `mTotal` will never update.

I've tried using `Class_Initialize()` but it gives `0` since the `.Quantity` and `.Price` are not passed to the class yet.

So how can I make this right?

Comment: Good question, but functional code that just needs to be improved/tweaked should really be posted on [codereview.se]. [so] is for broken code..

Comment: Why would you need mtotal? surely just  Public Property Get Total() As Double: Total = mQty * mPrice   is all you need?

Comment: Just calculate the total in your `Property Get Total`. There's no reason to store it in a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the `SetTotal`
2. Just calculate the total in your `Get Total()`

So you end up with

```
'clsItem Class Module
Option Explicit

Private mQt As Integer
Private mPrice As Double

Public Property Let Quantity(Value As Integer)
    mQt = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Quantity() As Integer
    Quantity = mQt
End Property


Public Property Let Price(Value As Double)
    mPrice = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Price() As Double
    Price = mPrice    
End Property


Public Property Get Total() As Double
    Total = mQt * mPrice
End Property
```